# Centos 7 Mail log?

Tags: centos

Previously I was using `tail -f /var/log/maillog` on **Centos 6**

When trying `tail -f /var/log/maillog` in **CentOS 7** it says:

```
cannot open ‘/var/log/maillog’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

So how to `tail` **maillog** in CentOS 7 ?

Comment: It seems the file `/var/log/maillog` does not exist..go to `/var/log` directory and check the files..

Comment: How its possible maillog is not there ? Can I install it ? ... btmp, dovecot-lmtp.log, freshclam.log, mariadb, tallylog, cbpolicyd.log, dovecot.log, httpd, openldap.log, wtmp, dmesg, dovecot-sieve.log, iredapd.log, postinstall.log, yum.log, dmesg.old, firewalld, lastlog, sa-update.log

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Centos7 that had no maillog.  Turns out `rsyslog` was simply not installed and I was doing just yum install syslog saying it was installed.

```
yum install rsyslog
```

The maillog was auto created

I was able to `tail -t` the file and see my mail activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the permissions of `/var/log/maillog`

```
ls -l /var/log/maillog
```

You will see

```
-rw-------. 1 root root 5844 Apr 26 20:58 /var/log/maillog
```

In CentOS 7, you have to belongs to sudoers and do

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/maillog
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of maillog is still the same in CentOS 7, so maybe it's just that nothing has written to it. Try creating a mail log event like this:

```
logger -p mail.info Testing
```

Then tail the log file again, and see if it's there. If that doesn't work, try creating the log file and try again:

```
sudo touch /var/log/maillog
sudo chmod 600 /var/log/maillog
logger -p mail.info Testing
```

If it still doesn't work, try restarting rsyslog with `sudo service rsyslog restart` and try creating an event again. If it's not there after that, it might be a problem in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.